# How to extract arguments using regex?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I want to extract arguments (type of command-line arguments) using regex. 
Here i will take the string as input and and get the arguments as groups

Basically i want the set in regex to both exclude and include some characters.

```py
import re

ppatt=r"( --(?P<param>([^( --)]*)))"
a=[x.group("param") for x in re.finditer(ppatt,"command --m=psrmcc;ld -  --kkk gtodf --klfj")]
print(a)
```

I want the output to be

```
['m=psrmcc;ld - ', 'kkk gtodf', 'klfj']
```

but the output is

```
['m=psrmcc;ld', 'kkk', 'klfj']
```

Comment: Just FYI, you can use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) if you're requirements aren't any different than normal command line args.

Comment: @ggorlen,thanks for reply.but in my case i need spaces and special characters also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `re.split`

**Ex:**

```
import re

print(re.split(r"--", "command --m=psrmcc;ld -  --kkk gtodf --klfj")[1:])
#or
print("command --m=psrmcc;ld -  --kkk gtodf --klfj".split("--")[1:])
```

**Output:**

```
['m=psrmcc;ld -  ', 'kkk gtodf ', 'klfj']
```

Comment: Don't even need `re` - `string.split` would work just as well.

Comment: Yep you are right :) `print("command --m=psrmcc;ld -  --kkk gtodf --klfj".split("--")[1:])`

Answer (score 1):

We might be able to solve this problem using a char list with word boundaries, maybe with an expression similar to:

```
(?:.+?)(\b[A-Za-z=;\s]+\b)
```

If we wish to have more chars, we will be adding it to:

```
[A-Za-z=;\s]
```

Here, we are not capturing the undesired chars by using a non-capturing group:

```
(?:.+?)
```

then we collect our desired chars wrapped in a capturing group, which we can simply call it using `$1`:

```
(\b[A-Za-z=;\s]+\b)
```

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(?:.+?)(\b[A-Za-z=;\s]+\b)"

test_str = "command --m=psrmcc;ld -  --kkk gtodf --klfj"

subst = "\\1\\n"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/L4qPL4/1/)